# Pulling remote commit into my fork

Tags: actionscript-3, git, github, egit

I want to pull a specific commit from another person's branch into my own branch. Both project are forks of the same project which neither of us owns. The person who made the commit has not sent a pull request to me, yet I want his changes in my branch anyway.

I'll give an example scenario,

1. Developer **Adam** has created a repository `Adam/GameLib` on GitHub.
2. I, **Andreas**, have made my own fork of this repository, and made some changes on a separate `Andreas/GameLib/dev` branch.
3. Another Developer, **Bob**, has made his own fork and noticed a bug, making the changes and pushing it as *a single commit* to his `Bob/GameLib/master` branch.

Bob has not made a pull request to neither me (Andreas) nor the original creator (Adam). Yet, I still want to pull Bob's single commit from `Bob/GameLib/master` into my branch `Andreas/GameLib/dev`.

How would I go about doing this *properly*? (i.e., not brute force downloading Bob's code as a zip and merging his changes into my branch with a text editor)

Comment: I am using EGit to reduce complexity, but I am just as fine with using the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add his repo as a remote to your repo

```
git remote add bob git://github.com/adam...
```

Add a branch for his changes

```
git checkout -b patch_branch
```

Now you can fetch Bob's changes

```
git fetch bob/master
```

and see if you can merge it into your own patch_branch

```
git merge bob/master
```

or you cherry pick his changes which you will have to look up elsewhere as this fully depends on what oyu are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

1. add the repositories you want to pull from as remotes,
2. pull from his master to your dev branch

For example:

```
git remote add bob git://github.com/bob/GameLib.git
git stash // optional, to allow branch checkout
git checkout dev
git pull bob/master
```

It's that simple.

Comment: Just a note, this solution worked just as well, but I'm only able to select one solution, so I accepted the first one posted.